# How to import app instance created from create_app()

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

How do I import `app` instance created in `app/app.py`'s `create_app()` function to be used in `app/api.py` since the `app` instance returns only to my `manage.py`?

My project structure:

```
project/
    app/
        api.py
        app.py
        models.py
        schema.py
        ...
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    README.md
```

I'm starting my dev app with command `python manage.py`

```
# manage.py
from app.app import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

```
# app/app.py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config['mysql']['db_uri']
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'pool_recycle': 3000, 'pool_pre_ping': True, }

    register_extensions(app)

    @app.before_first_request
    def setup_logging():
        gunicorn_error_logger = logging.getLogger('gunicorn.error')
        app.logger.handlers.extend(gunicorn_error_logger.handlers)
        app.logger.setLevel(gunicorn_error_logger.level)

    return app

def register_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
```

```
# app/api.py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

api = Api()


class TestGet(Resource):

    def get(self):
        app.logger.info('ok') ## Here I wish to use the app instance for logging
        return 'ok'

api.add_resource(TestGet, '/ok')
```

How do I import the `app`
instance into `app/api.py` so that I may use `app.logger.info(...)`?

If I call `create_app()` it will create a new instance and not the one that is already running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to import app.

You can use the `current_app` helper.

`from flask import current_app`

You can think of it as a proxy to the app instance.

Links to the official documentation:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#the-application-context

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.current_app

Miguel Grinberg also offers very good information on this topic:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure

(search for `current_app` on the page)

Comment: is it the same as adding ```app = Flask(__name__)``` in ```app/api.py```?

Comment: No, it is a proxy - imagine you look at the same object from two different windows. `app = Flask(__name__)` on the other hand creates a second instance. I'll update the above answer with the link to `current_app` in the Flask docs.